# jQuery - given a form. How to bind to alert AFTER the submit, ajax success

Tags: jquery

w jQuery is it possible to bind a success event to a particular form outside of the actual $.ajax, and in a way that doesn't bind to all ajax calls just the one in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function as normal and just pass the name

example

```
<script>
function submitSuccess(data)
{


}

$.ajax({
....
success: submitSuccess,
...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can specify a success callback for any call to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(r) {
        // Callback code here
    }
});
```

But from how I'm reading your question, I'm not sure this is what you're looking for.  How do you currently have the call to `$.ajax` hooked up?

Comment: right but I want to bind the success function from OUTSIDE of the .ajax call like you have above. Possible?

Comment: @AnApprentice: It would be helpful if you would edit your question and include the code you're currently using to submit your AJAX request.