# How do I bind a success behaviour to another ajax form submission?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618173/jquery-given-a-form-how-to-bind-to-alert-after-the-submit-ajax-success), I'm wanting to run a function when an ajax form is successfully submitted, but I don't have direct access to the initial ajax code that loads the form.

How would I check that the form was successful given that I can't add code to the initial ajax success call?

```
$('#registration-form').submit( function() {
  alert('registered successfully');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try binding .ajaxSuccess() to your element http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

```
$('#registration-form').ajaxSuccess(function() {
     alert('registered successfully');
});
```

> Whenever an Ajax request completes successfully, jQuery triggers the ajaxSuccess event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSuccess() method are executed at this time.

Comment: Thank you! If I follow this right, doesn't this mean I get the alert when #registration-form is loaded, and not when it is successfully submitted? In which case, I'd want to add .ajaxSuccess to the returned div rather than the submitted form. Correct?

Comment: You can add ajaxSuccess to any element.. I just did that to show you how it could be done.  It will trigger once any ajax request completes successfully.. And yes you would probably want to attach it to the return div.. that displays your message or w/e

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the [`ajaxSucess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) global ajax event handler:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
     alert('registered successfully');
});
```